# Home up navigation between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have an activity(say activity X) which contains a search box. On searching, I move on to another activity.( say Activity Y) I have used SherlockFragmentActivity to extend this Activity class and inside this activity I am loading a single fragment(say fragment A).

This fragment has many rows and on click of each row I am loading another fragment(say fragment B).

The problem is on clicking home button on my navigation bar from fragment B, Activity X is getting loaded and not fragment A.

I want fragment A to be loaded. How can I accomplish this?

What I have tried was: In my Activity Y,

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home :
            this.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the switch from A to B?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        newFragment=new FragementA(); 
        FragmentTransaction transaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.myFragement,newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        transaction.commit();
        return true;
}
```